# How are get/post requests santized in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using Yii2's gii to generate crud operations. Would like to know if it is safe to accept user input through these auto-generated forms or should I still need to write code to sanitize the inputs.

I've tried using  tags in the input boxes, the '<' character is changed to '%3F'.

**My question**

What security/sanitizations measures are built-in and what others are required. so that I don't keep repeating unnecessary operations which are already being done inside the framework.

Comment: It really depends on how you're going to use data. Usually you store data in the database as-is.

Comment: please throw more light. specifically what actually goes on inside.

Comment: I mean what happens to the data beginning from, when a post request is sent to the server, until when it becomes accessible by Yii::$app->request->post(). and also does some sanitation happen when $model->save() is called inside yii\db\ActiveRecord

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check whether framework library [CHtmlPurifier](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtmlPurifier) will offer what you need:

> CHtmlPurifier removes all malicious code (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, secure yet permissive whitelist. It will also make sure the resulting code is standard-compliant.

Yii uses this widget to purify posted data.

Comment: question is  about Yii -2.0 Dinesh!

Comment: though I shall accept the answer as i can find sth similar for 2.0